# AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that can allows any member on server to mute another member for 5 minutes once per day. I've found `member.timeout()` method in API reference, but have problems with it

Here's my code for muting:

```py
import discord
import datetime
import asyncio

class MyClient(discord.Client):

    listofmuted=[]

    def clearlist(self):
        self.listofmuted=[]

    def addtolist(self,newid):
        self.listofmuted.append(newid)
...
        if message.content[:5] == '!mute':
            if not message.mentions:
                await message.channel.send('No target to mute')
                return
            smallmute = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
            regularmute = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
            target = message.mentions[0]
            author = message.author
            if author.id in self.listofmuted:
                await message.channel.send('You\'ve already muted today')
                await author.timeout(smallmute)
                return
            #print(target)
            await target.timeout(regularmute)
            self.addtolist(author.id)
            #print(self.listofmuted)
            await message.channel.send('Target muted')
...
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run(token)
```

I've not copied listclear background loop, it seems to work correctly for now

When I test !mute command in chat I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\Pythony\bot\bot.py", line 53, in on_message
    await target.timeout(regularmute)
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'timeout'
```

Comment: With `discord.py 2.0` it works, with only minor tweaks to loops, as written in API Reference. Thanks to 3nws for pointing out version difference

Answer (score 0):

I think `Member.timeout()` only exists it `discord.py 2.0`. You can use `Member.edit()` instead.

```
await target.edit(timed_out_until=regularmute)
```

Comment: It's not throwing an exception at least. But seems to do nothing. I think I've installed 2.0 beta from github, the exception still here. I also can't edit timed_out_until directly, I'm getting `AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'timed_out_until'` as well. Guess I should wait for 2.0 proper release then. Or maybe I'm still using 1.7.something, is there a way to check? Thanks